# Change background color for toolbars and menus in Lyx

Tags: formatting

In Lyx 2.0, I would like to change the background color for toolbars and menus, make it darker. Anyone could suggest how I could do this?

Comment: This is not really on topic for TeX-sx. Customising the appearance of your editor depends on the editor, but here it really sounds like something that depends on your OS: the way windows look is normally down to settings there.

Comment: Sorry, my OS is Mac Lion. If my question does not belong in here, can you suggest where I could go to get an answer?

Comment: Here's a related question on SuperUser: [How to change the menubar color on a mac?](http://superuser.com/q/209671) Edit:  And [here's an app for changing menucolor](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/16640/menushade). For the LyX toolbar, perhaps ask on the LyX Users mailing list: http://www.lyx.org/MailingLists#toc2

Comment: @JosephWright: Could you still migrate this question to [su]? (I'm trying to get off-topic questions migrated consequently in order to "qualify" for more migration paths ...)

Comment: @doncherry We're only supposed to migrate where there is good 'value' in the question or answers. This looks like it would be a dupe on SU, so I don't think I'd be very popular if I migrated it.

Comment: @Sveinung Lyx is not off-topic, but altering your OS settings is. The downvote is unfortunate, but there is an 'automatic' downvote for off-topic material which is 'voted' by 'Community'.